# Вывести уникальные значения пересечения множеств

Tags: c++

У меня Time Limit на 10 тесте.(1.042 сек)

Вот задача:

Пересечение множеств

(Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб )

Даны два неупорядоченных набора целых чисел (может быть, с повторениями). Выдать без повторений в порядке возрастания все те числа, которые встречаются в обоих наборах.

Входные данные.
В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записано через пробел два целых числа N и М (1 ≤ N, М ≤ 300 000) — количество элементов первого и второго наборов, соответственно. В следующих строках записано сначала N чисел первого набора, а затем M чисел второго набора. Числа разделены пробелами или символами конца строки. Каждое из этих чисел попадает в промежуток от 0 до 105.

Выходные данные.
В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT нужно записать в возрастающем порядке без повторений все числа, которые входят как в первый, так и во второй набор. Числа разделять одним пробелом. Если таких чисел нет, то выходной файл должен оставаться пустым.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a>> b;
    vector <int> f;
    vector <int> s;
    vector <int> ans;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        f.push_back(x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        s.push_back(x);
    }

    sort(f.begin(), f.end());
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());

    int pred = f[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < f.size(); i++)
    {
        if (f[i] == pred)
        {
            f.erase(f.begin() + i); 
                i--;
        }
        else pred = f[i];
    }

    pred = s[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == pred)
        {
            s.erase(s.begin() + i);
            i--;
        }
        else pred = s[i];
    }
    int n=0;
    for(int i=0;i<f.size();i++)
        for (int j = n; j < s.size(); j++)
        {
            //if (f[i] == pred) { break; n = j + 1; }
            if (f[i] < s[j]) { break; n = j + 1; }
            else if (f[i] == s[j])
            {
                ans.push_back(f[i]);
                n = j + 1;
                break;
            }

        }
    for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << ans[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Дайте URL поиграться. Первая идея - использовать множества...

Comment: @Harry [задача](http://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=2&id_section=10&id_topic=4&id_problem=17)

Comment: Зачем это - `f.erase(f.begin() + i);`? Зачем явно удалять элементы? Подход у вас правильный, но бессмысленная трата времени на `erase` все убивает. Уберите нафиг все `erase` и просто не сохраняйте в `ans` одинаковые элементы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея решения совершенно правильная, а реализация - кривая.

Явное удаление повторяющихся элементов из исходных массивов через отдельный проход с `erase` в цикле - бессмысленная трата времени, из-за которой программа и не укладывается в отведенное время.

(Даже если и делать такую предварительную чистку массивов, то делать ее надо было бы через `std::unique` с последующим *единственным* вызовом `erase`. Даже тогда бы вы, скорее всего, уложились во время. А ваши `erase` в цикле - это тормозня неимоверная.)

Но на самом деле никакой предварительной чистки делать не надо, а повторяющиеся элементы надо отсеивать на этапе формирования результата.

Идею вашей реализации слияния/пересечения массивов через два вложенных цикла я понимаю, но уж больно она у вас неудобочитаема. "Симметричная" реализация (см. ниже) выглядит намного элегантнее.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  unsigned a, b;
  std::cin >> a >> b;

  std::vector<unsigned> f, s;
  std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<unsigned>(std::cin), a, std::back_inserter(f));
  std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<unsigned>(std::cin), b, std::back_inserter(s));

  std::sort(f.begin(), f.end());
  std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());

  unsigned prev = -1;
  unsigned i = 0, j = 0;
  while (i < f.size() && j < s.size())
  {
    unsigned vf = f[i], vs = s[j];
    if (vf == vs && vf != prev)
      std::cout << (prev = vf) << " ";
    i += (vf <= vs), j += (vs <= vf);
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Я не стал накапливать результат в отдельном векторе `ans`, а вместо этого сразу вывожу его в `std::cout`. Но это не принципиально.

Answer (score 0):

Схематично (в синтаксисах не силён):

```
int b[0..105];
cin >> a >> b;
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    cin >> x;
    b[x] |= 1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    cin >> x;
    b[x] |= 2;
}
for (int i = 0; i <= 105; i++) {
    if(b[i] == 3) { cout << i; }
}
```

Comment: Есть сильное подозрение, что `105` в условии задачи, это на самом деле `10^5` с потерявшимся при копипасте форматированием. :)

Comment: @Yaant Ну заменить 105 на 100000 - делов-то. По памяти проходим, а остальное ерунда.

Answer (score 0):

С++ like псевдокод. Должен проходить по времени за счет целых положительных чисел из не очень большого интервала.

```
int max = 100000;
int n; std::cin >> n;
int m; std::cin >> m;
bool* fst = new bool[max + 1]; // числа, входящие в первое множество
std::fill(fst, fst + sizeof(fst), 0);
bool* snd = new bool[max + 1]; // числа, входящие в первое множество
std::fill(snd, snd + sizeof(snd), 0);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int index; std::cin >> index; 
    fst[index] = 1; // отмечаем первое множество
}
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    int index; std::cin >> index;
    snd[index] = 1; // отмечаем второе множество
}
for (int i = 0; i <= max; ++i) 
    if (fst[i] && snd[i]) 
        std::cout << i; // если отмечены оба, то выводим число
```

Comment: Можете пояснить `bool* fst = new bool[max + 1];  
std::fill(used, fst + sizeof(fst), 0);
bool* snd = new bool[max + 1]; 
std::fill(snd, snd + sizeof(snd), 0);`

Comment: Индекс в массиве равен числу, о котором мы хотим знать, выдавать ли его в ответ. Выражение fst[123] = 1 означает, что число 123 есть в первом множестве, snd[123] = 1 - то, что оно есть во втором.

Comment: @FL4SH, Этот ответ прошел все тесты?

Comment: @Yernar, я скажем так тупо "закопипастил" этот код и у меня зацикливание. Еще не разбирался.

Answer (score 0):

Если на сайте выбрать компилятор Microsoft Visual C++ 2008, то такое решение проходит :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<int> mySet;
    int *arr = new int[100000],N,M, c, i;
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &c);
        arr[c] = 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &c);
       if (arr[c] == 1)
            mySet.insert(c);
    }
    for (std::set<int>::iterator it = mySet.begin();
            it != mySet.end(); ++it)
         printf("%d ", *it);

}
```